# Show Grid line of 2d Map in image

Tags: mapping, 2d, ros, slam, octomap

i had search through anywhere on google and forums
**but i couldnt found what i wanted.**
hope someone could help me here...

i had generated a 2d map from octomap using map_server map_saver from a pcd file it generated 2 file which is pgm and yaml file

however the generated pgm file **does not** have grid line on it.

my question is is it possible to show grid line on the image generated from map_saver? or is there any other way to generate an image with grid line from a 2D map?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, change the map dimension and if you have a different orientation rotate the map accordingly.

```
  import pylab as plt
  import numpy as np
  # Load the image
  img =  np.array(plt.imread("g_map.pgm"))

  # assume dimension of map 20mx20m
  map_dim_x = 20 
  map_dim_y = 20 

  # relationship between pixel and map  
  dx, dy = int(img.shape[0]/map_dim_x),int(img.shape[1]/map_dim_y)

  grid_color = 0

  img[:,::dy,] = grid_color
  img[::dx,] = grid_color

  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.show()
```

[image]